# Ruby's 'real?' method returns true for NaN and Infinity. Is this a bug or intentional?

Tags: ruby, floating-point, complex-numbers

I've stumbled into a weird behaviour in Ruby where the `real?` method on numeric classes incorrectly returns true on `NaN` and `Infinity`.
Eg.

```rb
irb(main):001:0> Float::INFINITY.real?
=> true
irb(main):002:0> Float::NAN.real?
=> true
irb(main):003:0> require 'bigdecimal'
=> true
irb(main):004:0> BigDecimal::NAN.real?
=> true
irb(main):005:0> BigDecimal::INFINITY.real?
=> true
```

Is this an intentional implementation decision or a bug to be reported?

Related Information:

- Ruby Version: ruby 2.7.2p137 (2020-10-01 revision 5445e04352) [x86_64-linux]
- Source that Infinity is not a real number: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/750787

Comment: Seems like being an instance of `Complex` is the only criteria. From [`Numeric#real?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Numeric.html#real-3F-method): _"Returns true if num is a real number (i.e. not Complex)."_ and from [`Compex#real?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Complex.html#method-i-real-3F): _"Returns false, even if the complex number has no imaginary part."_